Kotlin/Swing - simple way to declaratively generate generic UI to fill data object
I have a simple data model like this:
enum class Position {
  Left,
  Right
}

data class Tool_Window_Config(
  var window_id: String,
  var position: Position,
)

data class Width_Config(
  var less_or_equal: Int,
  var default_window_config: Tool_Window_Config,
  var tool_window_configs: List<Tool_Window_Config>,
)

I need to find a tool/library that will take an instance of this model and creates a Swing based UI including basic list management like add/delete item. If it has some nice things like support for some basic validation, that would be nice bonus.
I am looking for simple way to build such an UI in declarative way (declarative may be strong word, considering I want it to just explore underlying type and generate UI).
Result should be probably something like panel control of variable size depending on content, this will be put inside IntelliJ based plugin settings, I am not looking for something fancy, just workable, that would improve on my current JSON based config.

Hi @Jarek, do you find an answer for this?

Hi, so far nothing found, and anything that looked from Google like it could be useful was related to Android :(
